# pid of the currently executing process

Tags: linux, architecture, linux-kernel, scheduling

Friends, I am trying to trace the complete execution of an operating system including the processes running on top of it. For this I want the instructions executed by each process and its execution trace and I want to do this without having to go and take objdump of each process.

So my goals are : 
1) Building address space of each pid. 
2) Tracking execution of each pid.

For accomplishing above goals, I am running a linux-based operating system on top of an emulator Qemu.

When qemu encounters an instruction for the first time, i will check the pid of the process running this instruction using an io-port or a known physical memory address in the guest. I can then use this information to do the stuff that I want.

My problem is ....
where in the kernel/sched.c can i know the pid of the process that is going to be executed next. Means i am not able to figure a function call like -> launch_process(pid).Can somebody please point me to this location in the kernel. Or is there a known location in the system where we can track the address space. One is CR3 but i really cannot trust it.

For some guys this may seem to be a trivial pointer to this location but I am not able to find this location myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each process has appropriate `struct task_struct`. You can use `find_task_by_*()` functions to find `struct task_struct` by PID or `task_pid_*()` to get PID of given task. See also **"What is struct pid?"** section in `include/linux/pid.h`.

Running tasks are in per-CPU runqueue: see `struct rq` definition in `kernel/sched.c`.

Functions `try_to_wake_up()`, `wake_up_process()`, `wake_up_new_task()`, `context_switch()` and others are also related to your task.

Comment: @droid thanks ... context_switch is the function where the pid of the process executing changes. This is where i intend to put the code using task_struct next. Is there any other entry point for change of pid ?? Would this method would work for a smp system too ??

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the kernel so to answer surely about other such entry points. As for SMP - I think everything should be ok.